# Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";

Tags: reactjs, parsing, syntax-error

I am having a lot of issues in reactjs learning which I dont understand. I have `Line 5:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";` error in App.js and I can't understand what did i do wrong. Please help!!

I have tried to change the extension as well but doesn;t work

```
import './App.css';
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"; 
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "TodosList" from "./components/todos-list.component.js";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="container">
          <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://codingthesmartway.com" target="_blank"></a>
            <Link to="/" className="navbar-brand">MERN-Stack Todo App</Link>
            <div className="collpase navbar-collapse">
              <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li className="navbar-item">
                  <Link to="/" className="nav-link">Todos</Link>
                </li>
                <li className="navbar-item">
                  <Link to="/create" className="nav-link">Create Todo</Link>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>
          <br/>
          <Route path="/" exact component={TodosList} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax error

```
import "TodosList" from "./components/todos-list.component.js";
```

This should be

```
import TodosList from "./components/todos-list.component.js";
```

Comment: also if you can explain the difference between the extensions of components in ReactJS `componentname.js` and `componentname.component.js`. Both work for me but I dont know the exact difference

Comment: Both are correct; it's just a way we make things easy, giving extension which defines the purpose of that file. Like `componentName.test.js` will define it's a test file for that component. like that you can differentiate other files you use for that component only. Try one test framework or storybook you will get a clear idea behind that.

Comment: thanks loads.. I will again be posting something soon coz im about to start Jest testing in React. fingers crossed!